# Remove a node from xml using vtd in java

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

```
    <E id="1">
    .....
    <E id="2">
    ....
    </E>
    .
    .
    .
    </E>
```

I want to delete the complete node of  which is having id=2 from its parent node.
how to do this with Java?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use instantiate a copy of XMLModifier and call the "remove()" method. Let me know if you need more info on this.